# Fleet continuous delivery build

Tags: rancher, k3s, fleet

Working with continuous delivery in Rancher with the use of pipelines and Jenkins for building images was great for my use case because it build the image from source on the server. But considering the statement below from Rancher, I'm looking into fleet.

> As of Rancher v2.5, Git-based deployment pipelines are now recommended to be handled with Rancher Continuous Delivery powered by Fleet, available in Cluster Explorer.

It is unclear to me if I can also build the images from source with fleet or how to set this up. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Fleet you can build images from source to continue a GitOps-style CI/CD workflow. To connect a Git repo you use a manifest as described [here](https://fleet.rancher.io/gitrepo-add/). You should plan to migrate from the Rancher Pipelines workflow in Cluster Manager to the new Fleet workflow accessible from Cluster Explorer [as suggested](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/releases/tag/v2.5.0) if you want to continue receiving enhancements to your CI/CD workflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However what I'm looking to find is Automated Deployment. So I want to build images upon check-ins I do not want to do this manually as seems to be the case in the example you referred to. How is this possible?

Comment: The way I understand it is the fleet controller now monitors your Bundle Resources (which could be a Git repo, for example) and uses Drone behind the scenes to build and deploy the resources to one or many clusters. Is that not what you're looking for? Perhaps this will help: https://itnext.io/fleet-management-of-kubernetes-clusters-at-scale-ranchers-fleet-de161cc52325

Comment: I think @MrMedicine wants to build his docker image, push it to the registry and then deploy it in one go. I‘m struggling to understand myself how this is possible with Fleet. It seems to only handle the deployment part and not building and pushing images.

Comment: @SebastianR You are correct, it was confusing for me but I managed to setup automatic builds and push them to a private repo with gitlab, I then used flux to monitor the repo and update the deployments. My conclusion is that fleet is a great tool (especially if you manage many clusters) but does not provide a full CI/CD solution as Rancher pipelines did, in fact it does not even come close.